# What's the difference between enumerators, structs and classes?

Tags: c++, oop

So i've been learning c++ through www.learncpp.com/c++ primer and through the power of google for a while now and my goal has always been to make an RPG of some sort, even if it's a text based one.

Currently with my limited knowledge i'm trying to make a system that stores items/weapons/characters/spells/stats/etc.

- I know that structs have public variables by
  default and classes have private variables by default.
- I also know that they all store data

Only thing i don't know is what's the difference between all 3 of them and when i should be using each one.

Comment: enums are basically just names integers, you give names to values. For structs vs classes, my personal rule of thumb is POD -> struct, otherwise class.

Comment: `struct`'s and `class`'s are very comparable (members variables, functions, etc), but `enum`s have nothing to do with the first two. They are basically `typedef`'d `int`'s (more or less).

Comment: @Borgleader there are lots of people who will use `struct` as a shortcut when all the members are meant to be public. If you look at your standard library implementation you'll probably find some examples.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know, that's why I said *my personal rule* and made it a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modern C++ treats structs and classes the same, the only difference is that structs default to public while classes default to private. They are basically collections of data with associated functionality.
For example

```
class Player
{
   private:
      int health;
      int attack;
   public:
      void calculateHealth(int healthChange);
}
```

Enums are basically named numbers, for example:

```
enum Months {January=1, February=2 ...}
```

So now instead of saying `if currentMonth == 3` you can say `if currentMonth == Months.March`
Enums make the code easier to follow.

Comment: One could also mention enum class { };, which basically is like an enum, but doesn't allow implicit conversion from enum types to integers.